# Installation not working in Virtual Box from the command line when using a path with spaces for the install directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, powershell

I've been trying to run
`vbox-setup.exe --silent --ignore-reboot --msiparams INSTALLDIR="parent/child 1 2"`
but it always fails because the path has spaces in it. Using escape sequences does not work either

Comment: Where did you get `vbox-setup.exe`? Are you trying to install VirtualBox?

Comment: You tagged as PowerShell @stokedoverflow, so show the logic you are running this with powershell, just like you show from PS command line or using `start-process`. You might try with single quotes rather than double quotes for a quick thing to try though just in case but clarifying specific install time execution may be helpful otherwise e.g. `vbox-setup.exe --silent --ignore-reboot --msiparams INSTALLDIR='parent/child 1 2'`

Comment: @harrymc I got it from the official website. Yes, I'm trying to install it at a specific location via the commandline. This is for an inno setup script

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I did try that and it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try with `Start-Process` too like: `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path\vbox-setup.exe" -ArgumentList "--silent --ignore-reboot --msiparams INSTALLDIR='parent/child 1 2'"` or just the single quotes. Try this way if you haven't and want from PowerShell to see if it works. I hear some say there is no good reason to use `Start-Process` but it helps resolve these sort of issues in the real world for mass deployment of workstation software and such at a large scale with not using it doe not work otherwise.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Nope. This is not working as well

Comment: I'm not familiar with the parameters and how to handle this with that executable install file. It's likely specific to something with the installer or what it does not handle, etc. Maybe see: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#installation_windows for a better starting point or pick a directory without spaces in the meantime.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Yeah, I think I might have to stick to directories without spaces now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape:

```
vbox-setup.exe --msiparams TARGETDIR=\"D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
```

I've searched some hours and tested and it work perfectly ^^